# I have 177800 in my URL that points to my profile page, does this mean I was user 177800?

Tags: support, user-interface, profile-page, user-accounts, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is my user ID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98771/what-is-my-user-id)

I know that I have read that the stackexchange sites use SQL Server and `IDENTITY` columns, is this that number, or some other ID number?

I have `177800` in my URL that points to my stackoverflow profile page, does this mean I was user 177,800 to sign up on that site?

Comment: Yes, that's your unique user id.

Comment: @AnishGupta: Why do you think so? Not saying you're wrong, but the nth user having user ID `n` would make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is your unique user ID for ***that*** site. What I mean for "that site" is this: (my profile)

- Meta SO: [186285](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/186285/cole-johnson)
- Stack Overflow: [1350209](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350209/cole-johnson)
- Stack Exchange: [1426955](https://stackexchange.com/users/1426955/cole-johnson)
- Super User: [130931](https://superuser.com/users/130931/cole-johnson)
- Area 51: [58591](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/58591/cole-johnson)