# Every data explorer script I run for my username results in error

Tags: support, data-explorer

Every script I run on Data Exchange for my username results in the error `Invalid column name 'moses'.` I'm not as familiar with Data Explorer so I might be missing something really obvious. I've tried using the email address I use to log in with but that doesn't work.

I'm trying to run scripts to see badges progress on Superuser, but every other type of script I've run doesn't work either.

Here is an example:

[How long until I get the generalist badge?](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/12541/how-long-until-i-get-the-generalist-badge)

Comment: Once you're logged in to SEDE you should see this pre-filled in (if the parameter is named correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to enter your **user ID** (it's a number) in that field, not your display name. You can find it by visiting your profile and looking at the URL. Keep in mind it's different for each site.

Comment: I knew I was missing something :) Is there an official FAQ/Help article that explains this somewhere? Just so I know I can kick myself for not reading it, and if anyone stumbles across this question they can find it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use your user ID, not your user name. For you on Super User, that's 201262. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98771/what-is-my-user-id) for more information.